# Nmap reports host down in VM, OK on host

Tags: linux, networking, vmware, nmap

I connect to a VPN and perform port scans on the IPs there with Nmap on my host, and also within a Virtual Machine (VMware Workstation Pro 12.5.8) with an installation of Nmap.

A few days ago, the VM Nmap began to report that hosts are down for any scan I attempted. I can ping these hosts and connect to services such as web server and remote desktop but Nmap always returns a message like:

```
Nmap scan report for 10.11.1.5 [host down, received no-response]
```

The host Nmap continues to work as normal with the same command:

```
nmap 10.11.1.5

Starting Nmap 7.60 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2018-01-12 13:19 UTC
Verbosity Increased to 1.
Completed Ping Scan at 13:19, 2.68s elapsed (1 total hosts)
Initiating Parallel DNS resolution of 1 host. at 13:19
Verbosity Increased to 2.
Completed Parallel DNS resolution of 1 host. at 13:19, 13.00s elapsed
Initiating Connect Scan at 13:19
Scanning 10.11.1.5 [1000 ports]
Discovered open port 3389/tcp on 10.11.1.5
Discovered open port 139/tcp on 10.11.1.5
Discovered open port 1025/tcp on 10.11.1.5
Discovered open port 445/tcp on 10.11.1.5
Discovered open port 135/tcp on 10.11.1.5
```

Notably, running Nmap with the `--unprivileged` flag seems to work in the VM's case.

I've looked at the permissions on the `/dev/vmnet*` interfaces and notice they are owned by root, with rw only to root. Running vmware as root does not fix the issue. I've also tried updating to Workstation 14, with the same results.

Any insight into where I should be looking to restore the previous behaviour would be much appreciated.

Comment: Does nmap on your host still perform as expected? Is it being run as a privileged user?

Comment: @multithr3at3d Nmap on the host does perform as expected and it is not being run as privileged.

Comment: did you find a solution?

Comment: @Krypton I didn't unfortunately. I eventually edited my scripts / SPARTA to scan with the --unprivileged flag.